# what is the latest version of powerbuilder 12.5 or 13?

Tags: powerbuilder

Friends,
I have checked in the sap website for powerbuilder latest version and it shows 12.5 but one person who visited our company is telling that he is working on powerbuilder 13. is it true?
he double confirmed that he is working in powerbuilder version 13.

thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding the current versions of a specific piece of software. This information will go stale incredibly fast. Please ask these types of questions on product-specific support forums/chat rooms/mailing lists/...

Comment: Your answer appears to be rude and a complete waste of your time writing it and our time reading it. If you don't know the answer to the question you should just keep your thoughts to yourself instead of attacking someone for asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

12.5.2 is the latest version. The next version is going to be called 15 and is scheduled to be released next year.